# Splitting an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two javascript functions, the first one is working, teh second is working but not echoing the correct value in the hidden inputs.

Ive manage to get the last hidden input value correct but I'm not sure how

```
var customTicketsArr = Array();

function EditEventAddTicket(){
    alertWrongTime = false;
    var TicketName = jQuery("#ticketname").val();
    var TicketPrice = jQuery("#ticketprice").val();
    var ticketquantity = jQuery("#ticketquantity").val();

    var storeString = "TicketName" + TicketName + "TicketPrice" + TicketPrice + "Quantity" + ticketquantity + '';
    customTicketsArr.push(storeString);
    EditEventUpdateTickets(true);
}


function EditEventUpdateTickets(fade){
   jQuery("#custom_tickets_string").val(customTicketsArr);
   var output = "";
   var style = "";
   for (i = customTicketsArr.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
       ticketname = customTicketsArr[i].split("TicketName");

           ticketprice = customTicketsArr[i].split("TicketPrice");

           ticketquantity = customTicketsArr[i].split("Quantity");
       if(fade){
           if (customTicketsArr.length - 1 == i){
               style = "display: none; ";
               var fadeInDiv = i;
           } else {
               style = "";
           }
       }
       if (i % 2 == 1) { style += "background-color: #660000; "}
       html = "<div id='customticket" + i + "' class='customeventbase' style='" + style + "'>";
       html += '<input type="hidden" name="customTicketid[' + i + '][Name]" id="customticketName' + i + '" value="'+ ticketname  + '" />';
           html += '<input type="hidden" name="customTicketid[' + i + '][Price]" id="customticketPrice' + i + '" value="' +ticketprice[1]  +'" />';
           html += '<input type="hidden" name="customTicketid[' + i + '][Quantity]" id="customticketQuantity' + i + '" value="'+ ticketquantity[1]  +'" />';

       html += '<button class="customeventdel" type="button"  onClick="EditEventRemoveDate(' + i + ')"></button>';
       html += '<div class="clear"></div>';
       html += '</div>\n';

       output += html;
   }
   output += "<input type='hidden' id='custom_ticket_info' name='custom_ticket_info' value='" + customTicketsArr + "' />";
   jQuery("#custom_ticket_container").html(output);
   if(fade){
      setTimeout("EditEventfadeInDiv(" + fadeInDiv +")", 10);
   }

}
```

this outputs:

```
    <div style="background-color: #660000; " class="customeventbase" id="customticket1">
<input type="hidden" value=",testTicketPrice50Quantity44" id="customticketName1" name="customTicketid[1][Name]">
<input type="hidden" value="undefined" id="customticketPrice1" name="customTicketid[1][Price]">
<input type="hidden" value="44" id="customticketQuantity1" name="customTicketid[1][Quantity]">
<button onclick="EditEventRemoveDate(1)" type="button" class="customeventdel"></button>
<div class="clear"></div></div>
```

the values for the first two hidden fields are incorrect

Comment: Leaving code aside, can you explain what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why do you save it as a string? I would recommend storing it in an object:

```
function EditEventAddTicket(){
    alertWrongTime = false;
    var TicketName = jQuery("#ticketname").val();
    var TicketPrice = jQuery("#ticketprice").val();
    var ticketquantity = jQuery("#ticketquantity").val();

    var ticket = {"TicketName": TicketName, "TicketPrice": TicketPrice, "Quantity": ticketquantity};
    customTicketsArr.push(ticket);
    EditEventUpdateTickets(true);
}
```

and then you can simply load the data:

```
for (i = customTicketsArr.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
       ticketname = customTicketsArr[i].TicketName;
       ticketprice = customTicketsArr[i].TicketPrice;
       ticketquantity = customTicketsArr[i].Quantity;

       // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

They're not incorrect values - [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) is doing exactly what it is supposed to - returning an array of substrings after removing the separator.

With your string structure, splitting on `TicketName` will give you two strings - the substring before the separator and the substring after - `TicketName` itself is not included.

Thus, for the string `"TicketNametestTicketPrice50Quantity44"`, you will get `""` and `"testTicketPrice50Quantity44"` when you split on `"TicketName"` . Splitting the same string on `TicketPrice` will give you `"TicketNametest"` and `"50Quantity44"`.

I'd suggest putting objects into your array instead -

```
var storeObject = {
                    "TicketName" : TicketName,
                    "TicketPrice" : TicketPrice, 
                    "Quantity" : ticketquantity
                  };
customTicketsArr.push(storeObject);
```

You can then get back the data as:

```
for (i = customTicketsArr.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    var currentObject = customTicketsArr[i];

    var ticketname = currentObject.TicketName;
    var ticketprice = currentObject.TicketPrice;
    var ticketquantity = currentObject.Quantity;

    //do other stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just make a two dimensional array?

```
var customTicketsArr = Array();

function EditEventAddTicket() {
    customTicketsArr.push({
        'name'  : jQuery("#ticketname").val(),
        'price' : jQuery("#ticketprice").val(),
        'qty'   : jQuery("#ticketquantity").val()
    });
}
```